# Python: Difficulty Level of Logging into Websites with Script

Tags: python, http, authentication

I'm currently working on a personal python project whereby I need to be able to login to a group of websites (for which I have accounts) and then read the source code on my account page. Grabbing and reading the source code on my account page is no problem. The issue I have encountered is logging into the websites with python script.

I have looked at about half a dozen threads on this site, which specifically cover this topic, and experimented with the code and advice. Libraries I have experimented with include urllib2, requests, and mechanize. None of these have worked so far. Most of the time the scripts I use will grab the source code from the login page of the website and not my account pages (as intended). At the bottom of this thread are a couple examples of code I have used.

What I want to know is:

1. How difficult is it to log into a website with python script? Obviously there are libraries in python that handle this but does the task require advanced programming skills.
2. Will I need change the program for each website depending on how that respective website allows users to login? Are there some websites where logging in with script is not feasible?
3. Is there another language that would be better suited to this task?

I am not asking for someone to provide me with code (although feel free to do so) as I am perfectly happy to try and figure out this problem myself. However, my programming skills are still remedial and if this particular task is well above the pay grade of a beginning programmer then I would at least like to know that beforehand.

Example 1:

```
    import requests

    r = requests.get('https://www.websample.com', auth=('myusername', 'mypassword'))

    print r.content

    print r.status_code
    print r.headers['content-type']
```

Example 2:

```
    s = requests.session()
    login_data = dict(email='myusername', password='mypassword')
    s.post('http://www.websample.com', data=login_data)
    r = s.get('http://www.websample/page_with_info.com')

    print r.content
```

Example 3:

```
    import urllib2

    password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()

    top_level_url = "http://www.websample.com"
    password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, 'myusername', 'mypassword')

    handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)

    opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)

    data = opener.open('http://www.websample/page_with_info.com')

    urllib2.install_opener(opener)

    x = data.read()
    print x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming those websites don't implement some form of two-step authentication that use one-time keys sent to a device different from your pc, then it is perfectly doable. I've always used urllib2 for tasks such as these and initially started from [Doug Hellman's write-up](http://pymotw.com/2/urllib2/) on the matter, as well as the write-up from [Michael Foord](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml), that is linked to by the first. Very useful examples if you're new to it.

As for the answsers to your questions:

1. Nothing is ever difficult, once you know how to do it. I highly recommend reading the first 2 links, above.
2. Yes, you will need to change the program for each website. Websites are made by different people and they (usually) use different mechanisms for authentication. What you'll need is an application, such as [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) or [LiveHTTPHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/), that allows you to see what your browsing is sending and receiving upon logging in "manually". In that way, you can duplicate that behavior with your (python) script.

   I don't believe there are too many websites where it is impossible to do this programmatically. Even those that require 2-step authentication with a text message to your mobile phone for example could, theoretically, still be logged into purely programmatically by allowing your script access to your mobile phone somehow. It does make the task a whole lot more involved. However, websites with captchas are a whole other story, as these are purposefully designed to prevent such automated logins.
3. That depends on your experience entirely. It is possible to do in a lot of languages, I've even done it in bash. But in some, it's more elegant, like Python.

To give you an example of what I did some time ago to automate the filling in of forms that ask for confirmation after the first page, was to install LiveHTTPHeaders. I then stored the log of the communication session between my browser and the web server and noticed that some cookies were being set too. Once I added those to my urllib2 based script, I got a step further. After inspecting a few more of those logs, you'll eventually make your login automatic. Just make sure to keep sending all the cookies to mimic your browser in the best way possible.